# Passing values of inputs to variable array to create a URL string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, url, parameter-passing

The problem i'm trying to solve is I am wanting to have a simple stepped form on one page that gathers some basic data to create a URL string that then populates a calculator on another page.

I have the following code:

`var params = {
users: 500,
length: 24,
router: "Pay Monthly",
};

```
var queryString = $.param(params);
var myurl = "/calculator/?" + queryString ;

$( ".results" ).click(function() {  
    window.history.pushState('', "", myurl);
});`
```

In the above example, the number of users (500), length (24) and router (Pay Monthly) are the variables I would like to pass into the code above in order to create a string which is appended onto the URL.

In principle the above works with the static values i've given it, but i'm just stuck on how to get the values from HTML inputs.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

I have tried passing the above into an array to be parsed but it doesn't give the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) with a `<form>` element containing all the inputs.

```js
let queryString = $('form').serialize();
let myurl = "/calculator/?" + queryString;
console.log(myurl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="users" value="500"/>
  <input name="length" value="24"/>
  <input name="router" value="Pay Monthly"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for this. That's a really neat solution! It seems to be creating exactly what I need. One thing, how do I get the browser to actually go to the link? At the moment, when I hit 'results', it is replacing the URL in the address bar, but remaining on the existing page...

Comment: @junglist You can use `location.replace(newUrl)`

Comment: How would I alter this if one of the inputs was a <select> instead of a standard text input please?

Comment: @junglist It's the same. Just remember to set the name of the select.

Comment: I have done that - however it is just returning the first option:

'<select class="length-select" name="length">
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="36">36</option>
         </select>'

Comment: In fact, when I change the standard text input (the first option in the original example), it still just comes back as 500. How can this be made dynamic?

Comment: @junglist I can't reproduce the issue. You just need to serialize the form on submit. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/sh3j9xvd/